# from xml to php array,Infinite loops

Tags: php, xml

i wish export data from xml file to array.

(i know simple_html_dom is very fast - so use it).
Why always is Infinite loops?

```
<Response>
    <Placemark id="12">
        <address>LA 3, NY, USA</address>
        <Details>data1</Details>
        <Point>
            <coordinates1>-73.5850086,40.7207442,0</coordinates1>
            <coordinates2>73.5850086,-40.7207442,0</coordinates2>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark id="15">
        <address>LA 4, NY2, USA</address>
        <Details>data2</Details>
        <Point>
            <coordinates1>-71.5850086,22.7247442,0</coordinates1>
            <coordinates2>71.5850086,-22.7247442,0</coordinates2>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Response>

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'test.xml';
$xml = file_get_html($url);
$res = array();

foreach($xml->find('Response') as $e)
{
    $res[] = $e;
}
```

Comment: simple_html_dom is fast? compared to what? certainly not to any of the libxml based extensions PHP offers out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about `simple_html_dom`, but for parsing that XML you should be fine using the `SimpleXML` API.

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
echo $xml->Placemark[0]->address;

?>
```

Outputs: `LA 3, NY, USA`